# For $u\in H^s(\mathbb{R})$ with $s>n/2$, show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}u(x)=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

> For $u\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^m)$ with $s>m/2$, show that
>   $\lim_{x\to\infty}u(x)=0$

By the Sobolev embedding theorem $H^s(\mathbb{R}^m)\hookrightarrow C_b(\mathbb{R}^m)$ and this should pretty much be it? How would I proceed rigorously?

Comment: Not really. $C_b$ contains constant functions.

Comment: Thank you. I see the problem. I have tried to rewrite as $|u(x)|\leq(2\pi)^{-m/2}\int_{R^2}|e^{i\xi x}||\hat{u}(\xi)|d\xi$ but instead of the obvious $|e^{i\xi x}|\leq 1$ try to bound it with something depending on $x$. The hopes would be to write it as $|u(x)|\leq C\|u\|_{s,2}f(x)$, where $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$. But I don't seem to get anywhere with that strategy. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually use the fact that $C_c^\infty(R^N)$ is dense in $H^s(R^N)$ for each $s\in R$. (Or you could use $\mathcal{S}(R^N)$ instead of $C_c^\infty$. not really matters)

Anyhow, take $(u_n)\subset C_c^\infty$ be such that $u_n\to u$ in $H^s(R^N)$. Now, by embedding result, we have 
$$ \|u_n-u\|_{L^\infty(R^N)}\leq  C\|u_n-u\|_{H^s(R^N)}\to 0 $$

Now fix arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and find $n'$ so large such that 
$$  \|u_{n'}-u\|_{L^\infty(R^N)}<\epsilon $$
for all $n\geq n'$.

Because $u_{n'}\in C_c^\infty$, there exists $r(n')>0$ so large such that $u_{n'}(x)=0$ once $|x|\geq r(n')$. Hence a.e. $x\in R^N$ with $|x|\geq r(n')$, we have
$$ |u(x)|=|u(x)-u_{n'}(x)|\leq \|u-u_n\|_{L^\infty}\leq\epsilon $$
Taking into the fact that $u$ is continuous, we done.

Comment: Thank you. Give me a minute to think about it. I was going in a similar direction with Fourier transforms, so it doesn't feel distant.

Comment: So we have $\hat{u}(\xi)=\int_{R^m}u(x)e^{-i\xi x}dx\to0$ as $|\xi|\to\infty$. From this we want to deduce that $|u(x)|\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$. It shouldn't be so hard I guess but I'm starring myself blind on this problem. Should I try to bound it somehow or am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: Sorry I think I lead you to a wrong direction. Let me update my answer now. Sorry, I apologize.

Comment: Here is the answer you are looking for....